# How configure Java applet to work behind proxy?

Tags: java, proxy

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and have installed sun-java6-* packages.

My workstation is running behind an authenticated proxy, I've set the gnome proxy settings system wide and almost everything works fine, except for the Java applets that ask me for the proxy password but doesn't work when I type in.

Any ideas about how to make it work?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post, but perhaps explicitly changing the setting in the Java control panel might help:

- Open the Java Control Panel by running the command `javaws -viewer`
- In Control Panel: General > Network Settings

Then try changing proxy settings.

[image: Network Settings]

Comment: The command opens the "Trusted certificate viewer" program for me (openjdk-6-jre). Does the command work different with Oracle Java?

Comment: @Lekensteyn; Java Control Panel is only available for Sun/Oracle JDK --you will have to migrate to Oracle JDK if you want to use it.
However, when you install `Icedtea plugin`, javaws will use your browser proxy details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should set your proxy settings in /etc/environment and re-login.
Use this format: **http_proxy='http://username:password@domain:port/'**.
If it didn't work, use ***[CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net)*** to login to your proxy server instead. You can easily install it using ***Ubuntu software center*** or ***Synaptic Package Manager***.

Comment: the first way doesn't work.. and using CNTLM I didn't figure out how to use it. I appreciate if you can help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

Some distros/java versions/install don't provide shortcuts to the Java Control Panel, but running

`itweb-settings`

on your terminal will allow you to easily change your proxy settings.

[image]